# How to get args when call function with square brackets in the Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am the beginner of Ruby.
I get one problem when I read the Ruby code.
There have one function with square-brackets.
How can I get the args from that function?

Here is the Class

```
class Student
  class << self
    def count

    end
  end
end
```

Here is the function request.

```
Student.count["Jack"]
```

Comment: When I try to run the code, it shows some error msg: "NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: `count` needs to return something that responses to the `[]` method – a hash for example.

Comment: This isn't a function accepting an argument. `Student.count("Jack")` would be an argument. You can't get the string `"Jack"` inside the `count` method because that would involve using `()` to pass an argument in.

Comment: @meagar if `Student#count` returns _a function_, that obviously would be a function, accepting an argument (check `Proc#[]` for details.) If you meant it’s not a _method_, then you’re correct, save for nobody asked about methods. It makes sense to try to use an appropriate wording when commenting newbies.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I used exactly the wording I intended to use, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Square brackets have no special meaning in Ruby. It is rather a method `#[]` called on the receiver.

Amongst many others, this method is noticeably declared by [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html), [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) and [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html). Because of the parameter passed to `#[]`, which is `"Jack"` string, it is most likely either `Hash` or `Proc`.

That said, it depends on what is returned by `Student::count`.

**`Hash` example**

```
def count
  {"Jack" => 1, "Mary" => 2}
end

count["Jack"]
#⇒ 1
```

**`Proc` example**

```
def count
  ->(name) { "Hi, #{name}!" }
end

count["Jack"]
#⇒ "Hi, Jack!"
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much. This answer save my life in this day.
So can I image it like the mixture of in_array function of PHP and cout(*args)?

Comment: [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) returns boolean, while `Hash#[]` returns a _value_ and `Proc#[]` returns _a result of the call_ to `proc`. I am not sure I see anything in common.